# foreach loop print only one record from MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, fpdf

I am trying to print records of a table into a pdf file using fpdf, to this I am using for each loop, but it just prints one record though it works fine without fpdf class. here is the code:

```
if(isset($_GET['show_id'])){
    $id = ($_GET['show_id']);
    $comments = selectAll('proposal_comment', ['proposal_id' => $id]);

    foreach($comments as $comment){
        $pdf = new FPDF();
        $pdf->AddPage();
        $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
        $pdf->Cell(100,10,$comment['message']);
        $pdf->Output();
    }
}
```

any idea why is it like this?

Comment: Do you want 1 message per page? Or all the messages on one page?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I want all messages in one page.

Comment: Side note: `$id = ($_GET['show_id']);` < you don't need the `()` brackets here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the initialisation code outside the loop and then the loop will just add cells

```
if(isset($_GET['show_id'])){
    $id = ($_GET['show_id']);
    $comments = selectAll('proposal_comment', ['proposal_id' => $id]);

    $pdf = new FPDF();
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);

    foreach($comments as $comment){
        $pdf->Cell(100,10,$comment['message']);
    }

    $pdf->Output();
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, I am super noob in programming :)

Comment: You may need to work on the output inside the loop now [See the manual](http://www.fpdf.org/)